# ¿Cómo acceder a un archivo en otro paquete en JavaFX?

Tags: java, mvc, eclipse, javafx

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers con el SDK de JavaFX 11.0.2
Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0)

Tengo la siguiente situación, he creado una estructura de paquetes usando MVC para manejar los archivos de mi proyecto, he creado el paquete modelo, vista y controlador, y cada uno de estos tiene secciones para cada una de las partes del programa, por ejemplo: Login es un paquete que existe dentro de cada uno de los paquetes anteriormente mencionados, con el fin de tener una mejor organización a mi parecer de lo que estoy haciendo y tambien existe un paquete app al mismo nivel de la jerarquia de modelo, vista y controlador.

El problema radica en la forma que JavaFX carga los archivos .fxml, .css en el proyecto:

```
package app;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = (BorderPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("LoginStyle.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Como pueden ver los carga directamente usando el nombre, es decir es capaz de cargar los archivos del directorio actual de manera directa, como es creado en el sample cuando se inicia un nuevo proyecto.

Para solucionar el problema, necesito saber la forma de cargar los recursos del proyecto desde el paquete view.Login, en este caso, desde el paquete app. Para poder hacer uso de una mejor organización que la que genera el Sample de crear todos los archivos en el mismo paquete.

Este es el resultado que obtengo al intentar accederlo de manera directa, aun estando ubicado en el paquete en el scr, "view.login", he intentado "view/login/Login.fxml" y "view.login.Login.fxml" obteniendo el mismo resultado, donde no puede encontrar el archivo invalidando mi dirección. Espero su ayuda, estaré al pendiente

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at app.Main.start(Main.java:15)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

Como el archivo `.fxml` se encuentra en un paquete que no es el mismo paquete de la clase sobre la que llamas el método `getResource()`, o en un subpaquete de este, debes utilizar la ruta absoluta hasta este recurso. Esto se hace iniciando la ruta por el caracter `/`.

```
getClass().getResource("/view/login/Login.fxml")
```

Mi recomendación es este sentido es que siempre uses la ruta absoluta, ya que te puedes evitar dolores de cabeza futuros.

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado usando "../view/login/Login.fxml" para este tome en cuenta que debe retroceder un directorio, y busque el archivo en el otro paquete, de igual manera gracias por su aporte